# How can I expand a relative path at the command line, with tab completion?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history, autocomplete

In `bash` is there any way to expand a relative path into an absolute path, perhaps with tab completion?

I ask because sometimes I will search for a file, find it, then `vim` it:

```
cd /etc
cd apache2
cd sites-available
vim 000-default
```

Then I will do some other things and change directories:

```
cd /tmp
ls
cd ~
ls
```

Then I'll find that I need to edit the same file again, but it is not possible to use `history`, (or history search), because the file path is relative.

**Current Workaround**

If I know I'm going to be reusing a file a lot, after I find it I will grab the full path using something like `realpath`:

```
$ realpath 000-default
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default
(copy and paste path into next command:)
$ vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default
```

**Caveats**

This still requires copying and pasting. I believe there should be an easier way to get a file's full path into my history. What options do I have?

I believe that I have (accidentally) pressed some key combination before that expanded a relative path into a full path. I know in bash you can type:

```
cd /etc
ls bash_*(control+x *)
```

and get:

```
ls bash.bashrc bash_completion bash_completion.d
```

So is there a way I can expand a relative path into an absolute path, so that I can save operations on a file in my history with that file's full path?

Comment: You might want to start using `pushd` and `popd` so it's easier to go back to a previous directory: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Directory-Stack

Comment: @glennjackman - that looks really good. I found [this blog](http://eriwen.com/bash/pushd-and-popd/) and the comments really helpful, too. I'm also looking into `cdargs` now. Thanks! ps: if nobody else has a better answer just post that and I will accept it.

Comment: Another possible solution is to leave vim running while youre working around with files, and then bring it back up. You can do this by either doing `:sh` in vim to start a subshell, and then `exit` or CTRL+D to get back into vim. Or by doing CTRL+Z in vim to background (STOP) it and then `fg` to get it back.

Comment: [Similar question in zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12785/zsh-history-full-path)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find a good way to do that.

What I do is type `$PWD` before the file name, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand it.  In `bash` you may need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

e.g.

```
vi $PWD/000-default
```

then

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

then

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: damn. this is EXACTLY what I wanted to do. so simple! tab worked for me although ctrl+alt+e did not. I'm using a mac and iTerm2 to ssh to ubuntu. any way to set up something easier than `$PWD`? (the all caps is kind of cumbersome)

Comment: update: on mac OS X I realized I can press escape, then control+e to expand the current line even if bash's tab expansion is not enabled.

Comment: Right.  Esc+Ctrl+e is equivalent to Ctrl+Alt+e.  Esc sometimes works when Alt (or I guess Option on Mac?) doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

You could use programmable tab completion within bash for this:

```
function _vim_complete_file() {
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a FILES <<< "$( compgen -A file "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}" )"
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a COMPREPLY <<< "$( realpath "${FILES[@]}" )"
}

complete -F _vim_complete_file vim
```

Now if you type `vim 000`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will replace `000` with `/path/to/000-default`.

**Explanation**
The way this works is that `complete -F _vim_complete_file vim` tells bash to use the function `_vim_complete_file` whenever you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> on an argument to `vim`.
The function then runs `compgen -A file` on the current word the cursor was on when you hit TAB. This returns a list of files matching it.
That list of files is then passed to `realpath` which generates the fully qualified path. This list is stored as an array in `COMPREPLY` which the shell looks in for the available completions.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start using pushd and popd so it's easier to go back to a previous directory: http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Directory-Stack

I saw your comment about `cdargs` (which I assume is [this](http://www.skamphausen.de/cgi-bin/ska/CDargs)). For directories that I use frequently, I use an alias or function. For example

```
alias cgi='pushd /path/to/apache/cgi-bin'
```

or

```
docs() { pushd /path/to/apache/docroot/"$1"; }
```

The 2nd form is useful if there's a *parent* directory where the subdirs are frequent, then `docs foo` takes me to `/path/to/apache/docroot/foo`. The downside is you lose tab completion, but it hasn't been so arduous for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are re-editing in Vim, check out `:browse oldfiles` and `:help oldfiles`.

Comment: Also the number marks, `'0` etc.