# How can I expand all variables at the command line in Zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh, environment-variables, variable

In an earlier question, specific to bash, I asked [How can I expand a relative path at the command line, with tab completion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36547/how-can-i-expand-a-relative-path-at-the-command-line-with-tab-completion)

I liked @Mikel's answer that mentioned using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to expand all variables and I used that a lot.

Since then I've switched to `zsh` and while I can type `$PWD` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand the current directory's path, if I type something like `$PWD/.profile` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it does not get expanded.

I have read up on similar questions and have seen answers on expanding aliases as well as how to expand variables by typing them and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> but nothing that was the same as pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in `bash`.

Is there some way to allow an escape sequence such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to expand all variables in the command line that is being typed in `zsh` ?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150737 on the limitations of bash's C-M-E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up *compinit* to expand parameters in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

This is a minimal setting, if you have *compinit* already enabled, it should be sufficient to add `_expand` to the settings of `completer`

There is also the `expand-word` widget that is by default bound to `^X*` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>) that essentially does the same as the same binding in bash.

Note: Both methods only work on the current word.

---

As an alternative, in `zsh` you can actually do what you asked for in your original question: turn a relative path into an absolute path. Here is a slightly modified example from the `zshcontrib(1)` manpage:

```bsh
# load necessary utility function
autoload -Uz modify-current-argument

# define helper function for actual work
expand-and-abspath () {
    # expand the path (for example `~` -> `/home/youruser`)
    REPLY=${~1}
    # transform into absolute path (use `:A` if you want to resolve symlinks)
    REPLY=${REPLY:a}
}

# actual widget function
abspath-word() {
    # use helper function on current word
    modify-current-argument expand-and-abspath
}

# create zle widget `abspath-word` (with function of the same name)
zle -N abspath-word

# bind widget to "Ctrl+x p"
bindkey '^Xp' abspath-word
```

This defines the `abspath-word` widget, which replaces the current word with an absolute path representation and binds it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

To expand parameter, arithmetic and command substitutions (and not aliases and other forms of expansions), you could do:

```
my-expand() BUFFER=${(e)BUFFER} CURSOR=$#BUFFER
zle -N my-expand
bindkey '\e^E' my-expand
```

(it would have similar limitations  and could be almost as dangerous as `bash`'s one though).